# Cannot convert Double to expected argument type CGFloat

Tags: swift, quartz-core

How do i convert this function to swift? I'm getting an error I do not understand. You'll need "import QuartzCore" in your class.

Objective C Code

```
void DrawGridlines(CGContextRef context, CGFloat x, CGFloat width)
{
    for (CGFloat y = -48.5; y <= 48.5; y += 16.0)
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x + width, y);
    }
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, graphLineColor());
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Swift Code

```
func DrawGridLines(context:CGContextRef, x:CGFloat, width:CGFloat)
{
    for var y = -48.5; y <= 48.5; y += 16.0
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x + width, y);
    }
    //CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, graphLineColor());
    //CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: I'm unclear on the problem.  Is the title your error text?  Did you get the error on the first line of your loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift is very strict with variable types.  Since you didn't give `y` a type, Swift inferred that it was a `Double`.

Variable `y` needs to be a `CGFloat` because the function prototype that it is passed to is `func CGContextMoveToPoint(c: CGContext?, _ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat)`.  You can declare the type inline in the `for` statement:

```
for var y:CGFloat = -48.5; y <= 48.5; y += 16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to cast the `Double` value as `CGFloat` and the error went away.

```swift
let newCGFloatVal = cgFloatVal * CGFloat(doubleVal)
```